# ConEmu Text cursor only appears as Block or Rectangle

Tags: windows-7, conemu

**Background:** have been using ConEmu on a Windows 7 box for many months without issue, but after adjusting some _vimrc settings this afternoon the "Text cursor" option does not reflect the selection.

When attempting to change the text cursor in ConEmu, I am only able to switch between the "Block" and "Rectangle" options. Selecting "Horizontal (as console)" or "Vertical (as GUI)" leaves the cursor in the "Block" format.

However, selecting the "Rectangle" option **does** change the cursor to Rectangle, as shown in the screenshot at the bottom of this post. (The cursor is pictured with each of other selections as well.)

How can I fix my ConEmu settings such that selecting the horizontal or vertical options shows a horizontal or vertical cursor?

[image: conemu_cursor_does_not_change]

**Edit:** In an attempt to fix this issue I have tried both:

1. Resetting the defaults via the built-in `Settings... > Reset...` options
2. Remove the directory holding the ConEmu executables and packages then re-install from SourceForge

Since the remove/re-install attempt failed, I'm wondering if it could be caused by the _vimrc adjustments. Here's what that file looks like:

```
" Default Windows Vim stuff
" Vundle setup with packages
" Personal settings, like colorscheme, splitbelow, splitright, laststatus=2

" These are the lines I added:
" Airline-specific settings
set guifont=Powerline\ Consolas:h10
set encoding=utf-8
```

**Edit2:** Here is the full Settings page, as well as the default cursor on cmd.exe. Hopefully this helps!

[image: full_settings]
[image: cmd_default]

Comment: You have not shown full settings page.

Comment: Whoa -- couldn't ask for a more qualified helping hand! Updating my post with the full Settings page (as well as a screenshot of cmd.exe for reference) momentarily...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose Horizontal or Vertical cursor ConEmu uses the size of the cursor in the RealConsole (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to show it) unless you've specified `Fixed cursor size`.

The size cursor in the RealConsole may be broken in may ways too, for example in the registry

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"CursorSize"=dword:00000019
```

Comment: Hey @Maximus -- I noticed that when I check the "Fixed cursor size" boxes, the cursor behaves exactly as I would like. Awesome! If I can force the behavior I want then the "problem" I asked about above isn't really a problem but rather a lack of knowledge about customizing the cursor in ConEmu. My bad!

Comment: So your cursor "is broken" in real console and ConEmu just shows its real size.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The cursor in the real console, cmd.exe, is the horizontal cursor I would expect. When I do not check the "Fixed cursor size" tick boxes, the ConEmu cursor is a Block

Comment: Either way, by simply ticking the "Fixed cursor size" boxes I can get the desired cursor behavior -- so all is well as far as I'm concerned!

Comment: @Maximus - I'm getting this issue on alpha builds. Using tcc.exe with msys2. I have the same registry key value you specified. My cursor doesn't change in real console or in conemu. Any ideas?

Comment: @cchamberlain The key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console may have subkeys. Check them.

Comment: Thanks @Maximus, I got it figured out eventually, not sure what fixed it but I got msys2 / zsh / powerline fonts working solid now.